# Accepting client certificates without prompting user for certificate

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

When i setup the iis to accept client certificates, `<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />` it will accept certificates that is sent from any request. But when I access the site it will always prompt the user to select a certificate.

How can i turn off certificate prompt?

Comment: It is a client-side behavior and also depends on the browser and its settings as well as the number of client certificates the user has in their local certificate store.

Comment: So there are no headers that can be set to prevent the client browser not to prompt for certificates?

Comment: IIRC you can have the server send hints but the browser can happily ignore them. Taken from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108091/is-it-possible-to-automatically-select-correct-client-side-certificate). And [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/09/02/client-certificate-selection-prompt/) is the IE story.